# Ubuntu+Apache2+PHP7FPM - Very slow processing and CPU/Memory isn't efected

Tags: apache2, process, php7, php-fpm

I have a PHP data system that gathers information from a very slow external API. 
I run queries non-stop and it's super slow without effecting the CPU or memory.

What are the ways to maximize processing?

What is the best way to make sure and debug my Apache2 so I'm sure it's using the best maximized settings in terms of processing speed?

(I know that this might be because the slow API I'm using, but I really want to make sure that it's external and not internal.

Comment: There is no one sized fits all for tuning performance.  Going with the idea that the API is slow, you should add timers in your php script to detect where the delay is.  It should be very easy to find.  If you have massive slowdown on accessing the API, then there is nothing to be done.

Comment: You say "should add timers in your php script" you mean echoing the date (and time) in every process to detect where it's taking the most time? Is that the way to do it or is there a more advanced way?

And yes i know that if it's the API there is nothing to do, and I want to make sure this isn't the problem before finding other solutions

Comment: You can add a microtime() before the function is ran, and then after, you can subtract the time from the other and it will give you the execution time.  If your script is all over the place it will be harder to do.  If your code is broken into separate functions for getting data, and processing data, it should be only a few places you would need timers.